# Xcode and VisualStudio code synchronization while working with Xamarin.IOS or Microsoft.IOS in .net 7

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, xamarin.ios, .net-7.0

Hi based on the recent communication from Microsoft related to the end of life of Visual Studio for Mac I'm trying to look for the best way to replace the IDE and everything points to Visual Studio code as it is free and has multiple extensions as the MAUI and C# but I still have a big problem while using it.

Visual Studio has the option to open storyboards or xib files directly to Xcode, it creates a temporal Xcode project usually in obj app folder and after a save is done in Xcode it automatically synchronize the files in Visual Studio reflecting there the properties and changes done in Xcode.

Is there any extension that does this objective-C synchronization between VSCode and Xcode ? or could you please help me to point me a good approach to achieve this synchronization issue, I want to avoid the creation of an Xcode project manually.

I created a Xcode project and include all storyboards and xib files from my solution to modify the project directly in Xcode but I have this as a workaround as the best approach would be something like the synchronization between Visual Studio and Xcode where it is automatic and doesn't need the creation of a xcode project manually.

Comment: Did you install the corresponding expansion? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

Comment: thanks @JialeDu yes I've installed C# extension and .net MAUI extensions as my project is using Microsoft.IOS for .net 7

Comment: Do you follow this [Guthub Link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/681)? You can comment to express your opinions or make new reports.